# Figure Text in same Document with Anchor Tag

Tags: lua, luacode, directlua

I had referred this link: [Create Separate File using LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/606765/create-separate-file-using-lualatex/606807#606807)

But i have need in the same document.

I would like to give anchor tags in the `figure` caption and move the figure caption text in the top of the document.

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}


\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}
local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are components <figure id="ab8cf1" position="float"><label>Figure 1.</label><caption id="ab8cf1"><p>Carter&#x2013;Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; &#x221e; is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic id="ab8cf1" content-type="print" xlink:href="ab8cf1.pdf"/><graphic id="ab8cf1" content-type="high" xlink:href="ab8cf1.jpg"/></figure> used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment <figure id="ab8cf2" position="float"><label>Figure 2.</label><caption id="ab8cf2"><p>Carter&#x2013;Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; &#x221e; is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic id="ab8cf2" content-type="print" xlink:href="ab8cf2.pdf"/><graphic id="ab8cf2" content-type="high" xlink:href="ab8cf2.jpg"/></figure> in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <!--may smart structures--> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>
]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
dom:traverse_elements(function(el)
--local FigNo = el:get_element_name():match("%<figure id=\"(.-)\"")
--local FigCount = el:get_element_name():match("%<figure id=\"(.-)f([0-9]+)\"")
print("FigNo IS:",FigNo)
--dom=string.gsub(dom,"<figure id(.-)</fig>,"\\InsertFigure{FigNo}{f..FigCount}{}{b}")
end)
\end{luacode*}
\end{document}
```

I would like the result is:

```
    \begin{luacode*}
    local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
    sample = [[
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <art>
<figure id="ab8cf1" position="float"><label>Figure 1.</label><caption id="ab8cf1"><p>Carter&#x2013;Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; &#x221e; is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic id="ab8cf1" content-type="print" xlink:href="ab8cf1.pdf"/><graphic id="ab8cf1" content-type="high" xlink:href="ab8cf1.jpg"/></figure>
<figure id="ab8cf2" position="float"><label>Figure 2.</label><caption id="ab8cf2"><p>Carter&#x2013;Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; &#x221e; is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic id="ab8cf2" content-type="print" xlink:href="ab8cf2.pdf"/><graphic id="ab8cf2" content-type="high" xlink:href="ab8cf2.jpg"/></figure>
    <title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
    <para>Smart testing structures are components \InsertFigure{ab8cf1}{f1}{}{t} used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment \InsertFigure{ab8cf2}{f2}{}{t} in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <!--may smart structures--> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
    </art>
    ]]
```

Comment: where does the `<figure>` elements come from? they are not in the source document.

Comment: @michal.h21: In the source doument please refer `are components <figure id="ab8cf1" `. Figure element comes with `attribute` tag.

Comment: @michal.h21: I will use separate `XML` and separate `Lua` Script and run in terminal/command prompt (like: lua figure.lua filename.xml). It's good idea or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that LaTeX code is useful in this case. Just make a standalone Lua file and use `texlua` to execute it:

```lua
kpse.set_program_name "luatex"

local domobject = require "luaxml-domobject"
sample = [[
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<art>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are components <figure id="ab8cf1" position="float"><label>Figure 1.</label><caption id="ab8cf1"><p>Carter&#x2013;Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; &#x221e; is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic id="ab8cf1" content-type="print" xlink:href="ab8cf1.pdf"/><graphic id="ab8cf1" content-type="high" xlink:href="ab8cf1.jpg"/></figure> used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment <figure id="ab8cf2" position="float"><label>Figure 2.</label><caption id="ab8cf2"><p>Carter&#x2013;Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> &#x3d; &#x221e; is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic id="ab8cf2" content-type="print" xlink:href="ab8cf2.pdf"/><graphic id="ab8cf2" content-type="high" xlink:href="ab8cf2.jpg"/></figure> in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <!--may smart structures--> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>
]]

local dom = domobject.parse(sample)
local figures = {}
local figno = 0
-- insert \InsertFigure
dom:traverse_elements(function(el)
if  el:get_element_name() == "figure" then
  figno = figno + 1
  local figid = el:get_attribute "id"
  -- save the figure element for later processing
  table.insert(figures, el)
  -- replace figure with \InsertFigure
  local parent = el:get_parent()
  local new = parent:create_text_node(string.format("\\InsertFigure{%s}{%i}{}{b}", figid, figno))
  el:replace_node(new)
end
end)
-- move <figure> elements
local art = dom:query_selector("art")[1]
if art then
  -- we want to insert figures at beginning of the <art> element
  -- we saved <figure> elements in dom:traverse_elements
  for i, figure in ipairs(figures) do
    art:add_child_node(figure, i)
  end
end

-- print transformed xml
print(dom:serialize())
```

Run:

```
texlua sample.lua
```

It will print the following result to the terminal:

```lua
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<art><figure id='ab8cf1' position='float'><label>Figure 1.</label><caption id='ab8cf1'><p>Carter–Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> = 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> = 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> = ∞ is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic content-type='print' id='ab8cf1' xlink:href='ab8cf1.pdf'></graphic><graphic content-type='high' id='ab8cf1' xlink:href='ab8cf1.jpg'></graphic></figure><figure id='ab8cf2' position='float'><label>Figure 2.</label><caption id='ab8cf2'><p>Carter–Penrose diagram for the inverted black hole spacetime. The lines <italic>x</italic> = 0 are repulsive singularities, the intersecting lines <italic>x</italic> = 1 form a Killing horizon, and <italic>x</italic> = ∞ is a temporal infinity.</p></caption><graphic content-type='print' id='ab8cf2' xlink:href='ab8cf2.pdf'></graphic><graphic content-type='high' id='ab8cf2' xlink:href='ab8cf2.jpg'></graphic></figure>
<title>Scattering of flexural waves an electric current</title>
<para>Smart testing structures are components \InsertFigure{ab8cf1}{1}{}{b} used in engineering applications that are capable of sensing or reacting to their environment \InsertFigure{ab8cf2}{2}{}{b} in a predictable and desired manner. In addition to carrying mechanical loads, <!-- may smart structures --> alleviate vibration, reduce acoustic noise, change their mechanical properties as required or monitor their own condition.</para>
</art>
```

Comment: Thanks for your immediate help and i have got many ideas using Lua Script. Thanks again.

Comment: Instead of printing in terminal how to overwrite with `Input XML` file?

Comment: @Balaji you can redirect terminal output to a file using `texlua sample.lua > file.tex`